# Override default component settings in grapesjs?

Tags: grapesjs

I am using GrapesJS in a CMS. By default, added blocks come with component settings defined in this file:

https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/blob/dev/src/dom_components/model/Component.js

How do I override the default component settings so they can be applied globally to all components within my custom blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
grapesEditor.BlockManager.get('image').set({
    content: { style: 'color: "black"; max-width: 962px;' },
});
```

Where `grapesEditor` is the instance of the editor that you get when initalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to update defaults for built-in components? I have bold text inside  element. All bold elements should have default highlighted: false. I tried this config but no success

```
Editor.DomComponents.addType('text', {
  model: {
      defaults: {
        tagName: 'b',
        highlightable: false,
      }
    }
  });
```

I don't use any storageManager and elements b, i etc. are always highlighted. When I use storageManager local, element are ok and not highlighted.
[image]